# c++ array/pointer declarations issue

Tags: c++, declaration

I'm trying to solve the difference between three following declarations in c++. I appended my guesses:

- `const float *x[4]` - 4-element array of pointers on arrays of constant floats
- `const float (*x)[4]` - I'm confused here... is it the same as above?
- `const float *(*x)[4]` - the same as above but "on arrays of arrays of constant floats"

Any help/explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Get `cdecl` and don't look back.

Comment: @CarlNorum definitely, you're right. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cdecl` to know declarations,

1. `const float *x[4]` - Declare **x as array 4 of pointer** to const float
2. `const float (*x)[4]` - Declare **x as pointer** to array 4 of const float
3. `const float *(*x)[4]` - Declare **x as pointer** to array 4 of pointer to const float

Source : [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/)

Answer (score 2):

```
const float *x[4] - 4-element array of pointers on arrays of constant floats
```

4-element array of pointers to constant floats.

```
const float (*x)[4] - I'm confused here... is it the same as above?
```

Pointer to 4-element array of constant floats.

```
const float *(*x)[4] - the same as above but "on arrays of arrays of constant floats"
```

Pointer to 4-element array of pointers to constant floats.

Answer (score 1):

```
const float *x[4]    -  An array of pointers to constant floats
const float (*x)[4]  -  A pointer to an constant float array with 4 elements
const float *(*x)[4] -  A pointer to an array of pointers to constant float
```